# BSOD hal.dll+12a3b

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod

This is a reoccurring problem, could someone give me an idea as to the cause. This has been happening on a brand new Dell Precission M4700

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 101013-12636-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 10/10/2013 17:21:31
Bug Check String  : 
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000124
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 2       : fffffa80`09f25028
Parameter 3       : 00000000`fe200000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00021136
Caused By Driver  : hal.dll
Caused By Address : hal.dll+12a3b
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75bc0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\101013-12636-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 300,448
Dump File Time    : 10/10/2013 17:22:15
==================================================
```

Comment: 0x124 = fatal HW error (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Upload the dmp file (skydrive, dropbox) so that we can analyze them.

Comment: Fore reference, hal.dll is [Hardware Abstraction Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#Hal.dll). Maybe reinstalling or repairing Windows might work. Have you updated all hardware drivers?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard no, this DLL only calls the function to halt the system (hal!HalBugCheckSystem).

Comment: @magicandre1981 where are you reading that?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I know it, because I analyzed a lot of those 0x124 dumps.

Comment: @magicandre1981 At any rate, let's wait for the Original Poster's input.

Comment: Hi , here is a link to .dmp files    http://sdrv.ms/18Sznkz

Answer (score 0):

the dump shows that you have issues reading data from the L2 Cache:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: fffffa8009ea1028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000fe200000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000021136, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for intelppm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for intelppm.sys

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 hal!HalBugCheckSystem
02 nt!WheaReportHwError
03 hal!HalpMcaReportError
04 hal!HalpMceHandler
05 hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous
06 hal!HalHandleMcheck
07 nt!KxMcheckAbort
08 nt!KiMcheckAbort
09 intelppm


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa8009ea1028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01cec294d64e2164
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 10/6/2013 13:41:04 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8009ea10a8
Section       @ fffffa8009ea1180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Data Read
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306a9
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000007

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8009ea10f0
Section       @ fffffa8009ea1240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000007
CPU Id        : a9 06 03 00 00 08 10 07 - ff e3 ba 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ fffffa8009ea1240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8009ea1138
Section       @ fffffa8009ea12c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : DCACHEL2_DRD_ERR (Proc 7 Bank 5)
```

If this is a brand new Dell, contact their support so that they can replace the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been dealing with Dell over this issue for a couple of weeks and have been getting told continually to re install the system which I felt was not the answer to the problem, I have also tried opening the Nvidia control panel and it has told me no Nvidia graphics card in in the system, there should be a Nvidia Quadro K2000m !!!!

Comment: have you installed the Quadro driver (not the normal Geforce driver)?

Comment: @ magicandre1981: I contacted Dell with the findings from above and received an email from them to say an engineer will be calling on Tuesday to replace the CPU, Memory and Graphics cards. To answer your question when I performed the re-install it was using Dell restore to factory settings which is supposed to load all necessary drivers etc.